# Decrease the height of title bar in Visual Studio 2012 on secondary screen

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2010, .net-framework, visual-studio-2012, title-bar

I have two screens on my VS2012. No problems with title bar on the main screen, on the secondary however, the title bar takes up lots of space - see screenshot attached.

In VS2010, for example, the title bar on secondary screen is a lot thinier. I guess this change was made to address touch interfaces (??) but it is highly inconvenient to waste some much space just because of that.

Anybody knows how the change just the height of the title bar on the secondary screen?

Over one screen
[image]

and over two screens
[image]

Comment: Its very unlikely you will be able to change the height of this part of the interface.

Comment: So, are you saying that it looks fine on your primary monitor, but not the secondary?  Can we get a similar screenshot of the primary monitor?

Comment: @heavyd, well it has exactly the same height on the main screen but it does not look so empty there is a quick launch box on it plus the title bar is customized. Even putting something on these title bar would be better than just letting all that space to simply waste.